# Google assistant activate after pressing button on headphones

Tags: headphones, google-assistant

I'm using Redmi Note 8 Pro (Android 10, MIUI 12.0.2, not rooted) and headphones with one button.
I have turn off Google assistant, however when I press button it activate Google assistant (or some other assistant).
When I listen music and want pause player, I press button on headphones, and instead of pause music, it activates some assistant. This assistant after few seconds say, that didn't understand and music play again.
How to turn off activating this assistant after press button on headphones?

Comment: Is the device rooted?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket No, it's not rooted,